# Multiple iOS apps with single database and single log on

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I created multiple apps in android with single database (Content provider) , single log on (which means if i login in one app it should work for all , if I logout from one app it should logout from all other apps) , I have to open one app from another app and every day I have to update all my off line data to server (it should happen particular time on every day ) . Now I am going to port this system (all apps) to iOS , is it possible in iPhone ?  And I am not going to submit this apps to app store.

Comment: why did you tag your question with the `android` tag?

Comment: Because I already implemented same in Android  , so common developers of android and iOS can easily give a suggestion for me

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You would need to save your database at container url which you can get using:

```
- (NSURL *)containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:(NSString *)groupIdentifier;
```

The `groupIdentifier` param needs to be same for all the apps and needs to be configured inside Target->Capabilities->App Groups.

Once you have configured same appGroup for each application, you can use above method to save database at the location, provided by the method. That way the same DB would be accessible to all the apps.

There is NSUserDefaults init methid which takes suitename(appGroup), and creates a shared UserDefaults, which can be used for your single log-on purpose.

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuiteName:(NSString *)suitename;
```

Refer:

[containerURLForSecurityApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati)

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1409957-initwithsuitename)

Comment: Thank you Puneet sharma for your quick response , can you give some detailed example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AppGroups` to share files between your apps. Using `AppGroups` you can implement a `Single Sing-On` functionality by storing a `Bool` in your database that each of your apps have access to that indicates whether the user is currently signed in or not and act accordingly when opening one of your apps.

Comment: Thank you David Pasztor , How can I open one app from another app and how can i upload all my data to server every day on same time (for this i am using android service) , what is the alternative in iOS ?

Comment: You can't automatically open your app from any other apps, `iOS` requires user interaction for that. You have to provide a link to your in in your other apps that the user can click on to launch your app. However, if you use a shared database you don't need to open the other apps to upload their data to the server. You just have to make sure, the data is written to the database before any of your apps would close and then you only have to upload the contents of your database from one of your apps daily.

Comment: User is doing some work at offline after some hours that device connected to internet so there is a possibility to go all my apps for Suspended state before coming that device online.

Comment: You don't need to have internet connection to save to a local db. As for how to set up the daily task in one of your apps, you can find several answers already on SO.

Comment: You are correct David , but daily I have to update my local DB to server at mid night  , at that time my apps may or mayn't in running state, that's why I am using service in android

Comment: And I am telling you, you only needs one of your apps to be running since you are storing all of your data in a shared location, so any of your apps can upload the data of all applications. And as I have already stated, you can find methods for scheduling recurring tasks in `iOS` by searching here on SO.